# Backbone View calling another View - Now can't catch click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I thought I read you could have one view call another view like this:

View 1

```
window.View1 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "click .start" : "start"
    },

     start: function () {
       var StartView = new View2({model: this.model});
    }
})
```

View 2

```
window.View2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    events: {
        "click .nextstage"   : "nextstage"
    },

    nextstage: function () {
     alert('NEXT STAGE COMING UP');
    },

    render: function () {
        $("#content").html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

So the router sets me up with view one and I click on "start" and it takes me to view 2. Then I want to click on Next Stage and have the View 2 Method trigger based on the click.... but it won't fire. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe [marionettejs.com](http://marionettejs.com) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View2` renders to `#content` and according to your code `#content` is not an element (`el`) for the view. Since `events` property waits for events that happen inside of view's `el` it won't work.

Try

```
// View 1
start: function () {
    var StartView = new View2({model: this.model, el: $('#content')});
}

...

// View 2
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Backbone will unwrap the `el` on its own so you can just say `el: $('#content')`.

Comment: @muistooshort that is definitely a cleaner way. I didn't know that. Thank you. I'll update my aswer.